# Locked out of my outlook.com email that had 2 step verification on

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, two-factor-authentication

I have a Microsoft Outlook.com email address, and I had 2 step verification on. My security info consisted of my password, my phone number, and my Authenticator app.

I had forgotten my password since quite some time now but I was a bit careless thinking that I still have my phone number and authenticator app to get inside. But yesterday, my brother did a prank: deleted the authenticator app and all data was wiped out all of a sudden. Since 2 step verification was on for my outlook.com email account, I was essentially locked out.

Is there ANY possibility that I can ever get back into my account?

I checked for some ways, and I found one "recovery form", but I sadly discovered a note in small hand-writing: *If you had enabled 2 step verification, you can't recover your account this way.* Well then in *what way* could I recover my account?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please kindly check if you have saved your password in your device's keychain or browser.
If not, based on my research, you also couldn't recover your account via "recover form" if you have enabled 2 step verification as you mentioned.

So, for your issue, I'm afraid that you need to directly contact the account support via these links:

- [Email Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/get-account-help-by-email-bb65aa6a-9135-31df-0b36-d6318d6f4e0f)
- [Chat with Microsoft support](https://partner.support.services.microsoft.com/zh-cn/contact/form/23/msa/)

Hope that would be helpful to you.